# Sorting is not working on a column which is not a database column Rails 6.1.4.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6.1

We have a view with orders listed in table view and it has the following columns

1. Order id
2. Order desc
3. Order date and time
4. Order to be delivered at

Now here in this column "Order to be delivered at" it shows a fixed time i.e to be delivered within 30 minutes.
so in this column, we always have 30 mins added to the "Order date and time" field.
As this field is not in the database and does not come in the orders data collection then how should I add sorting to this column "Order to be delivered at"?

Is there any other way to do it in rails 6.1?

currently, I'm sorting my orders like this

```
@orders.order(column_name: :sort_order)
```

and I'm getting this error

```
ERROR:  column "delivered_at" does not exist.
```

any help would be appreciated.

And if there is any other best way to handle this situation, please let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case sorting by "Order to be delivered at" is equal to sorting by "Order date and time", as those fields are related. So you can use db field for sorting
In you controller do

```
SPECIAL_SORTS = {
  delivered_at: :order_date
}
```

then in you sorting method:

```
def apply_sort(column)
  if SPECIAL_SORTS.key?(column)
    column = SPECIAL_SORTS[column]
  end
  sort(column) # do your sorting by db column
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Kindoloki for your response. I'll implement this.

Comment: @Manoj please accept answer if it works

Comment: thank you for your help. and I also had to make some changes to the sortable function only then It worked but as you directed me to the right direction so I'm accepting this answer.